# nested lists to implement adjacency lists in c++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, stl, graph-theory

i was going through the code for topological sorting on [this website.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/) 
i understood the code except for one part which is the declaration of the adjacency list (on line 15), which is

```
list<int> *adj;
```

basically, to me, adj should be a pointer to a list of integers but in this case based on how they have used it, it is a list of lists ... so shouldn't a list of lists be

```
list <list<int> > adj;
```

*can someone please explain this to me?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also do it like that, however what this website is creating is an **array of lists**, not exactly a list of lists. I think this approach (array of lists) is the usual way to represent adjacency lists in lots of programming languages.
In this way the vertices are numbered from 0 to V-1, and you can access the list of adjacents directly by using the index operator adj[i]

I don't really know the exact reason, but I imagine it's for efficiency purposes.

EDIT:
Notice that lists are, according the C++ reference, double-linked lists, so if you want to access element i, an iteration through the linked nodes is needed until you reach element i. With an array, you access directly the list that you are interested in, without iterating and therefore more efficiently.
In [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) we can read:

> The main drawback of lists and forward_lists compared to these other sequence containers is that they lack direct access to the elements by their position; For example, to access the sixth element in a list, one has to iterate from a known position (like the beginning or the end) to that position, which takes linear time in the distance between these. They also consume some extra memory to keep the linking information associated to each element (which may be an important factor for large lists of small-sized elements).

Comment: oh i see. But since the first case is a pointer to an array of lists then shouldn't it be list<int>[] *adj  ?

Comment: I think that syntax is more Java-like than C++. In any case, when we create arrays we use a pointer to the first element. This is the way it is done in C and C++, actually by default when you create an array, the required memory is allocated and a pointer to the first element is returned

Edit: Actually, I think this way you would create an array of pointers to list, and not a pointer to an array of lists

Answer (score 1):

It's important to note that the code you've linked to is rather unidiomatic. One prominent issue it has is exactly with that member you mentioned, `list<int> *adj`.

In modern C++, we tend to avoid using [`new` and `delete` directly](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rr-newdelete), when instead, we could use a smart pointer (e.g. `std::unique_ptr`) or a container. In this specific case, instead of:

```
list<int> *adj;
// ... etc. ...
Graph(int V) {
    adj = new std::list<int>[V]; 
}
```

it would indeed be better to use:

```
std::vector<std::list<int>> vertex_adjacencies;
// ... etc. ...
Graph(std::size_t num_vertices) : vertex_adjacencies(num_vertices) { }
```

Now, as for your suggestion of a list-of-lists - that's also possible:

```
std::list<std::list<int>> vertex_adjacencies;
// ... etc. ...
Graph(std::size_t num_vertices) : vertex_adjacencies() 
{
    auto empty_adjacencies = std::list<int>{};
    std::fill_n(
        std::front_inserter(vertex_adjacencies), 
        num_vertices,
        empty_adjacencies);
}
```

but it would require rewriting various other methods. Also note, that the graph is intended to have a fixed number of vertices, without vertices being added or removed, so placing the vertex-specific adjacency in a list does not make a lot of sense. (Not that a separate std::list for each vertex' adjacencies is such a good idea, performance-wise, anyway, but never mind that).